# Equation solution in modular arithmetic

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation, cryptography, euclidean-algorithm

Given two primes $11$ and $5$, find all $α > 1$ such that $α^{5} \equiv 1 \mod 11$.

How would you compute that?

Comment: Since the numbers involved are so small, trying the elements of $\Bbb Z _{11}$ one by one shouldn't be that difficult. Also, if you have computed $a^5$ and $b^5$, then $(ab)^5$ is just a multiplication away.

Comment: I wouldn't like to apply brute force..

Answer (score 1):

A small table will do:
$$\begin{array}{r*{5}{c}}
x &\pm2&\pm3&\pm4&\pm5\\
\hline
x^2& 4&-2&5&3\\
x^4 &5&4&3&-2\\
x^5&\mp1&\pm1&\pm1&\pm1\\
\hline
\end{array}$$
Hence the solutions are 
$$\alpha= 1,\;-2,\;3,\;4,\;5. $$